# The square root of evil (the demi-forbidden = the suberogated?)

Tags: deontology, non-classical-logic, conceptual-analysis

Pursuant to the general question of demi-operations in logic, I wondered today about demi-*forbidding*, √**FR**. So luckily enough, my question is simple enough:

1. Via Fregean conceptual analysis, or Rawlsian, can we (A) rigorously redefine the word "suberogation" as "demi-prohibition" or (B) effectively replace the one term with the other?

I ask this because the SEP article on supererogation [raises some objections to a *prima facie* analysis of the suberogatory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/supererogation/#WhaSupProDef):

> Another issue raised by attempts to subject the concept of supererogation to some version of the general schema is that of “offence” or “suberogation”: if there are non-obligatory well-doings (supererogation), are there also — as their mirror image — non-prohibited wrong-doings (“permissive ill-doings”)? Or in other words, are there

> > v. actions that are bad to do but not good not to do

> Some philosophers (Chisholm 1963, Richards 1971,  Forrester 1975, and Driver 1992) were attracted to the logically neat symmetry of supererogation and suberogation, but a critical examination of this artificially invented category demonstrates both the difficulty in filling it with content and flaws in the general schema itself (Heyd 1982, Mellema 1992). Examples for typical “offences” are hard to come by. At most one can think of permissible bad action in relatively trivial cases, like taking too long in a restaurant while others are waiting, which is inconsiderate rather than immoral (Ullmann-Margalit 2011). These are uninteresting cases from a moral point of view as are their supererogatory counterparts of small favors or acts of politeness. An interesting, though controversial, example is ingratitude, which is traditionally considered as a grave sin (gratitude being a duty), but which some treat as typically suberogatory (Wellman 1999). But once we look for examples of morally vicious or villainous action that is nevertheless permissible (which is the counterpart of a morally heroic action), we find it difficult to come up with an example. This should hardly be surprising. By its nature, a moral system does not leave patently bad action as morally permissible. In that respect, good and bad, the virtuous and the vicious, are *not* symmetrical from the deontic point of view: the good is open-ended in a way that the bad is not. The extremely good cannot be required, but the extremely bad (vicious) is the prime target of prohibition. However, more recently Paul McNamara has suggested a rich conceptual analysis of the supererogatory which although leaving the question of asymmetry open, points to important analogies between the supererogatory and the suberogatory. These can be shown once we switch our attention from the agent-evaluative component of suberogation as “offence” to the objective, act-evaluative element of “permissible suboptimality” (McNamara 2011).

For some extra "flavor," though, consider the question of the *logarithm* of evil. In other words:

2. If extraction-of-roots and taking-of-logarithms can both be used as inverses of logical production, here, might there be *two* dire seasonings we can sprinkle on our moral discourse, and suberogation proper is one of them (distinguished from demi-prohibition in general, or as a specific subgenre of the demi-forbidden)?

Comment: This is interesting in light of a prior question you made and effectively answered. Given my interest both in analysis of evil and the employment of complex numbers in physics, I may try a jab at responding later today (if I don’t I’ll delete this comment).

Comment: @Hokon one obstacle I somewhat foresee is that we still will be left wondering which actions, concretely-speaking, really satisfy the intended "description." However, considering prof_post's question about permissible self-deception, alongside the apparent role of "inner lying" in Kantian radical evil, and then the whole problem of *akrasia*, I do wonder if self-deception, when it founds other ills, is then the *radix malum* in *both* senses, here, of that word *radix*?

Answer (score 0):

To some extent, it appears that the answer to the question, or the answers to the subquestions, will depend on whether the following are equivalent:

1. √**OB**¬*A*
2. **OB**√¬*A*
3. √**OB**√¬*A*

Offhand, I expect that (1) and (2) would be interchangeable, but not (3) with those. At any rate, since **FR***A* = **OB**¬*A*, it's hard to think that (1) and (2) would not be tantamount to demi-prohibition. Moreover, then, even if the "logical root of obligation" is not acceptable, we have the work of Humberstone and Paoli to fall back on in support of demi-negation regardless (and if we have a positive operation like  (for "it is actual that" or whatnot) that is opposed to ¬, then **OB**√*A* smuggles a functional equivalent of demi-obligation back into the picture anyway).

---

***Some other epiphanies:***

I guess you *maybe* can solve the puzzle of [multiple flavors of permission](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-deontic/#OptiVsIndi) along these lines, along with the puzzles [of the bad Samaritan](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-deontic/#ChisPuzzSDL), [of the gentle murderer](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-deontic/#TwoTypeDetaTwoWaysEnriSDL), and [of the burned letter.](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-deontic/#RejeCorePrinSDLOBNECOBRM)

1. Taking **PM***A* = ¬**OB**¬*A*, you get six other varieties of permissibility by running through the demi-operations, here.
2. All three of the other puzzles can be solved by cleverly situating  throughout the sequents/disjuncts. At least, my intuition is yelling this at me *very* loudly.

*Why* is my intuition screaming so? Because of the following two things Bumble informed me of some while ago:

> Another example is that the following is apparently false:

> > It is possible that the person who invented the zip did not invent the zip.

> But the following is true:

> > It is possible that the person who actually invented the zip did not invent the zip.

So, for example, "It is obligated that the letter be mailed," goes to, "It is obligated that the letter be mailed or that the letter be burned," but ***not*** to, "It is obligated that the letter be mailed or that the letter be *actually* burned." QED?